# Ubuntu on Wayland

Tags: wayland

So, recently I noticed a settings like icon next to the sign in button on the login screen. Upon clicking it I am presented with two options:

1. Ubuntu
2. Ubuntu on wayland

Why has this suddenly appeared?
Should I be worried?
What is Ubuntu on wayland?

I am running a persistent live Ubuntu 18.04 (the latest version as of 24 April 2019). I also noticed that it does not appear on my other persistent live version of Ubuntu 18.04 (the latest version as of 24 April 2019)

Comment: no need to worry.. they are different display servers.. the default is Ubuntu on Xorg.. other is Ubuntu on Wayland.. Ubuntu on Xorg simply shows Ubuntu..

Comment: I believe that the intention (in the greater Linux world) is to move to Wayland over the course of time.  It mostly works, but there are some points that still need improvement.  This affects me, because I've learned to use Xorg to control some of my devices, and I have not yet learned how to get similar results in Wayland.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: See this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland

Comment: @pomsky note last update of the article is in 2017. Current Gnome is on mutter (again).

Comment: I noticed, that my old and weak Lenovo G550 with T3000 Celeron 1.8 GHz processor have better performance if I play videos in youtube using Google Chrome. They are playing without latencies I see on Xorg based DEs. On XFCE it works better than on Unity Xorg or Budgie.

Answer (score 23):

at the graphical login screen, you may see an icon either next to the login name, or at the top of the screen on the right; the icon may look like a settings industrial toothed wheel icon, or it may look like the ubuntu 3-branch symbol;

if you click on this icon, you may see:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu on Wayland
```

or you may see this:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu on Xorg
```

**Xorg** and **Wayland** are **display servers** (not to be confused with **display managers**, such as **lightdm** or **gdm3**, or with **desktop environments**, such as KDE, Unity, LXDE, XFCE, Openbox, Fluxbox, etc)

what this means, seeing these 2 options, is that you have one desktop environment, namely Ubuntu, and 2 display servers installed, and you can choose whichever you want; so which one should you choose?

Xorg has been around a long time, so it is likely that all linux programs work with it; so if you don't want to have things not working anymore, choose Xorg;

Wayland is new, and some programs do not work with it, such as gparted, or screen recorders, etc; one question here even noted that Wayland turns off your nvidia, causing the laptop to heat up;

to see which display server you are using, in a terminal/at a command prompt try this:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

so, if you are trying Wayland and things don't work, log out, click on the icon on the login screen and choose Xorg then log back in.

Also if you have more than one display manager installed, for example you have gdm3 and lightdm, to check which one you are using, type at a terminal command prompt:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

and to switch between them type

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

A text window appears where you can use the arrow keys to select one of the installed display managers and press enter.

It is possible to install other desktop environments as well, such as one or more of these or others, and then they will also appear in the list of desktop environments which you can choose from, before logging in:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
sudo apt-get install lxde
sudo apt-get install openbox
sudo apt-get install fluxbox
```

Then the desktop environments list to choose from before login might look like this:

```
Fluxbox
LXDE
Openbox
Plasma
Ubuntu
Ubuntu on Wayland
Xfce Session
```

Comment: I have 2 desktop environments. Vanilla GNOME and Ubuntu GNOME. No matter what I do, I can't uninstall all meta-packages which are made only for Vanilla-gnome.

Comment: Wow, Thank you Jmarina, this is so detailed.