# Only the first four letters are visible on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I'm able to see only the first four letters of a file manager, terminal, and other default tools of Ubuntu 20.04 after updating today's update.

Does anyone have the same issue? How can I resolve it?

Only web browsers are working correct output. Even the terminal has the same issue. I can't even run commands!

Note: I have tried to change the font through Tweak Tools, and I've also tried from the setting.

Comment: I have also tried this solution (URL: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328971/letters-all-scrambeld-only-4), but it's not working for me. I'm using AMD Cedar (ATI Radeon HD 5450).

Comment: I can't wait so long because that's my business pc. Hence, I've reinstalled everything today. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Seems like a lot of people are getting the same issue. So did I. @PeterVinsel's solution in this thread here worked perfectly for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328913/400658 . Maybe it'll work for other people too.

Comment: partly fixed by changing display server from `ubuntu` to `ubuntu on wayland` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138155/ubuntu-on-wayland. But some apps still with the same problem e.g. archive manager. Also tried change fonts in gnome-tweaks and noticed, that in broken apps fonts are not changing totally.