# Ubuntu 20.04 Update corrupts system fonts?

Tags: 20.04, fonts

I'm a bit of a noob, so let's get the apologies out of the way.  I ran the update that came today, and after restart all the fonts in the UI are cut off (I guess that is the best way to describe it)?

I've tried reinstalling Unity, tried changing the system font, changing the scaling... no luck.

See image for better description:
Screenshot showing font issue [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYzPv.png)

```
 *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Barts PRO [Radeon HD 6850]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:35 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe6e0000-fe6fffff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: That looks like a broken graphics driver to me. Please add the output of `sudo lshw -C display` to your question, formatted as "preformatted text" (with a line of three backticks before and after).

Comment: Others are having this problem. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330100/only-the-first-four-letters-are-visible-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts   and https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=333 for example.

Comment: I've not had any luck getting this resolved yet.  I've tried the solution provided by @Peter-Vinsel and that didn't work.  I've got a temporary work around in by using the AMD provided drivers, but they have their own issues.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: This error keeps showing up:  Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]